# Best way to store a large amount of floats in a file with Python?

Tags: python, floating-point, numbers, file-writing

I have a program that generates a very large sequence of floating point numbers, usually around tens of millions. I need an good way to store them in a file. I'll be writing them in sequence, and reading them using Python. The floats are in a one-dimensional array like this:

```
[39534.543, 834759435.3445643, 1.003024032, 0.032543, 434.0208...]
```

(These numbers are examples, and I just keyboard-mashed to make them.)

Code to generate the numbers:

```
for x in range(16384):
    for y in range(16384):
        float = <equation with x and y>
        <write float to file>
```

Comment: "Best" as measured how?

Comment: Have you done any research or tried anything yet?

Comment: Most convenient, but still fairly fast and small file size.

Comment: I tried writing them in plain text, but the file was very large.

Comment: A "ver large" sequence resulting in a "very large" file. Surprising.

Comment: It's much larger than it needs to be. There are 255 characters per byte, but I was only using 12 of them. I'm asking how to write the floats in a more efficient way.

Comment: Maybe something like TinyDB?

Comment: How large is that plain text file if you compress it? (zip, bzip, lzip, whatever?)

Comment: And can you share the code to generate the numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the floating point numbers as 64-bit doubles using the `struct.pack` function:

```
from struct import pack, unpack

array = [39534.543, 834759435.3445643, 1.003024032, 0.032543, 434.0208]

with open('store', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(pack('d' * len(array) , *array))
```

so that you can later retrieve the values of the array using `struct.unpack`:

```
with open('store', 'rb') as file:
    packed = file.read()
    array = unpack('d' * (len(packed) // 8), packed) # 8 bytes per double
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of your numbers look too short to be random. So you might be able to store them in *less* than 8 bytes per float with compression. For example:

Store:

```
import lzma

array = [39534.543, 834759435.3445643, 1.003024032, 0.032543, 434.0208]

with open('store', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(lzma.compress(repr(array).encode()))
```

Load:

```
import lzma, ast

with open('store', 'rb') as file:
    array = ast.literal_eval(lzma.decompress(file.read()).decode())

print(array)
```

Even with random data, I get less than 8 bytes on average:

```
>>> n = 10**5
>>> a = [random.random() for _ in range(n)]
>>> len(lzma.compress(repr(a).encode())) / n
7.98948
```

Admittedly it's rather slow, though, at least with my random data. Might be faster for non-random data. Or maybe try a lower compression level or one of the other compressions. The `pickle` module also mentions compression, so that might be worth a shot.